# How do I open my Ebook library in kindle?

Tags: kindle, ebook-management, windows, library

I recently saved my library of kindle ebooks onto a flash drive (I got my nephew to do it for me). I have the file saved on my desktop now and it's quite a few books (10 gigs). Now I have windows 8 and have the kindle app but have not the slightest idea on how to save all these books to the kindle app locally, without using the internet. The books are in a folder format of Author - titles - data.
So I have 1 folder called Kindle, in this folder i have countless folders of the names of all the authors I have and in each of those the titles of the books by that author and in that I have the data for that specific book which is 3 different files; a '.opf' , '.mobi' and a '.jpg'. Now these I presume are the cover the book itself and the mobile version?

Anyways I really would just like to copy this file locally so that I can browse my books on the kindle app.

Answer (score 2):

In Calibre, the Add books menu choice has several options. One is:

"Add books from directories, including sub-directories (Multiple books per directory, assumes every ebook file is a different book): Allows you to choose a directory. The directory and all its sub-directories are scanned recursively and any ebooks found are added to the library. calibre assumes that each directory contains many books. All ebook files with the same name in a directory are assumed to be the same book in different formats. Ebooks with different names are added as different books."

If you ***point to the folder*** and use that Add option, it will do them all,see this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are wanting to read these Kindle books on your PC, right?

I use the fantastic and free application called Calibre Reader.
You can get it at:

http://calibre-ebook.com/

It's very easy to intall and manage.  Once you start it you can just tell it where your books are and it will import them all from the disk location.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried this software but i have to individually add each file... and I have thousands of files.

Comment: You should be able to drop all the files in a folder and you can choose import from a folder.  I believe there is even an option to scan subdirectories in case the files are in subdirs below the first one.

Comment: No David, you don't have yo manually add them, see my answer.